# Is it possible to pull a ServiceNow KB article out of SNOW in its entirety?

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I'm curious if it's possible to pull the entirety of a SNOW KB article out and store it in a CSV or document. I'm asking because based on the exjsting endpoints that doesn't look possible.

The most content I seem to be able to pull from these endpoints would be articles.snippet. Is that correct, or would I be able to use these to pull entire articles? If so, how would I make that happen?

Comment: I think that is possible. You will have to create rest api for that. You can just send the HTML part of KB Article using REST API outside of the servicenow

Comment: @RUSHIKESHNARWADE Could you elaborate more on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull the full HTML by specifying articles.fields.**text**.display_value

[image: ServiceNow Knowledge article body field name]

Comment: Thanks for this. Which API endpoint in SNOW KB would I be using?